# Spring-MVC Thymeleaf from not submitting

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new to spring and I've tried coding a prototype.

I've tried making a form. Whenever I press the submit-button, nothing happens.
I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.3 with Oracle OpenJDK 15.0.2. I've tried Firefox and Chrome. The js-console is empty.

This is my model (`Patient.java`):

```
public class Patient implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    // Geters and seters
}
```

My Controller (`PatientController.java`):

```
@Controller
public class PatientController {
    @GetMapping("/patient")
    public String patientForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("patient", new Patient());
        return "addPatient";
    }

    @PostMapping("/patient")
    public String patientSubmit(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient patient, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("patient", patient);
        return "addedPatient";
    }
}
```

My `addPatient.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>HTL-Testet Prototype</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add a patient</h1>
    <from action="#" th:action="@{/patient}" th:object="${patient}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="number" th:field="*{id}"/></p>
        <p>Firstname: <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}"/></p>
        <p>Lastname : <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}"/></p>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </from>
</body>
</html>
```

My `addedPatient.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>HTL-Testet Prototype</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add a patient</h1>
    <p th:text="'Added ' + '[' + ${patient.id} + ']' + ${patient.firstname} + ' ' + ${patient.lastname}"></p>
    <a href="/patient">Add another patient</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` tag on the `addPatient.hmtl` page is wrong, **if you change it to `form` tag as below, the problem is solved:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>HTL-Testet Prototype</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add a patient</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/patient}" th:object="${patient}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="number" th:field="*{id}"/></p>
        <p>Firstname: <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}"/></p>
        <p>Lastname : <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}"/></p>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```